# Visual Studio can't see .cpp files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, linker

Visual Studio can't see `.cpp` files or at least that's what I believe is happening. First things first if I create a new project and add some `.h` files under `Header Files` and some `.cpp` files under `Source Files` I can just include any header and I am good.

However, I have a folder somewhere which contains some modules (`.h` and `.cpp`). I go to the project properties -> additional include directories and everything is great.. or not? Yes, now visual studio can see all the .h files that I include, but when I try to compile, I get linker errors (unresolved symbols) for basically everything. Which probably means visual studio can't see the `.cpp` files.

That said, what can I do?

Comment: When you compile it. First of all compiler find entry point which is main, definately declared in some cpp file. What is your problem can you clearify more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS can't see the .cpp files because it's not looking for them. To get the symbols in that module, you would have to compile the source code or link to an external library.

You have two options. You can add the .cpp to the solution, so that they compile with your project. Alternatively, you can compile the external code to a library add this to additional dependencies.

Since it's an external module, you might like to use the second option.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio is not supposed to somehow "see" `.cpp` files by itself. If you want your `.cpp` files to be compiled as part of some project or solution, you have to explicitly *add* them to that project. You have to do it manually.

You already added some `.cpp` files to your project, as you describe at the beginning of your post. Why did you suddenly decide that you don't have to do it for those other `.cpp` files as well?